# Limit the number of active sessions for a set of users

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

In Oracle there is 'Oracle Resource Manager' (ORM) for resource management.

Amazon AWS RDS documentation contains a comparison between ORM and what a postgres equivalent could be: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/oracle-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-oracle-aurora-pg.special.dedicated.html

For the ORM-feature 'Limit the number of active sessions', the documentation says that in postgres one can

> Manually detect the number of connections that are open from a
> specific application and restrict connectivity [...] with database
> procedures [...]

And it gives this query as a mean to identify the number of active sessions per usename:

```
select pid from pg_stat_activity 
where usename in(
  select usename from pg_stat_activity where
  state = 'active' group by usename having count(*) > 10
  )
  and state = 'active' order by query_Start;
```

**How exactly would one now restrict connectivity with a database procedure based on the detected number of active connections? What would such a procedure roughly do?**

My concrete scenario is that I have users from the synchronous parts of the application and users of the asynchronous part. Connection pooling is used, but there are several connection pools unfortunately and not one. So there are ~200 connections from the connection pools of the async parts of the application. What I want to do is to have a limit that a maximum of 10 sessions of these async connections may become active at the same time. When the 11th wants to become active it shall wait until one of the others is back to idle. (I looked at AWS RDS Proxy to do this, but this is not my first choice)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question correctly, you can use ["connection limit"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html#:%7E:text=NOREPLICATION%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20BYPASSRLS%20%7C%20NOBYPASSRLS%0A%20%20%20%20%7C-,CONNECTION%20LIMIT%20connlimit,-%7C%20%5B%20ENCRYPTED%20%5D%20PASSWORD%20%27) settings for each user. You cannot detect and kill them right on time, but you can set a limit in advance.

```
alter user $your_username connection limit $connectionlimit;
```

You can also limit amount of memory for each user by tuning work_mem for each user.

Comment: Thank you for the input - `connection limit` though seems to limit how many connections can be made. What I want to achieve is to keep the number of connections as they are, but limit how many of those connections may become active at the same time.